# Can I select n different fruits from m bags using matrices

Tags: matrices, permutations

I am trying to solve a programming problem which as far as I can see boils down to the following mathematical problem.

I have $n$ different types of fruit.
I have $m$ bags, which contains 0, 1, or more distinct items of fruit

What is the best way of determining whether I can:

> Remove a single piece of fruit, from each of $n$ bags (out of $m$), so that I have one of every type of fruit.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to visualise the problem, but I have been able to do so using a matrix of $0$s and $1$s, where the columns represent fruit types and the rows represent the different bags. The problem then boils down to:

> Is there a permutation where every column contains a $1$, each being in a different row.

Four bags (rows) and 3 types of fruit (columns)

There are two solutions: Rows 1,2,3 or rows 1,2,4.
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right)
$$

Four bags (rows) and 3 types of fruit (columns)

No solution exists.
$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right)
$$

Sorry if I haven't classified this problem correctly, please feel free to add the relevant tags.

Comment: This is the "marriage problem" in another form. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem

Comment: I don't think you have explained clearly what constitutes success:  consider $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{array}\right)$$  Are rows $1,2,3$ a solution?  Each column is copied in another, but in your first example both rows $1,2$ have a $1$ in the first column.

Comment: Fair point Ross, I have updated the question to clarify what constitutes a solution. In you example 1,2,3 are indeed a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to find an answer but it's not elegant and it doesn't use matrices. However I found a way of reducing the problem: to

$f(n, m) = f(n-1, m-1) + g(1) + g(2) + ... + g(n) $

where $g(x)$ is a boolean function that says fruit type $x$ is one of the $m$ bags.

I can solve $g(x)$ quite easily in my program, and eventually I get $f(1, m-n)$ which again is trivial to solve.

Thanks for all the help, it made things a lot easier when I could tell me boss this problem actually had a name, and was not trivial.